# Why I keep getting this error on mysqli_connect function

Tags: php, mysqli, slim

I have an index.php which part of slim api framework app. when I include mysqli_connect function, I'm getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in /home/zent/public_html/apps/slimpro/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
```

I remove the line 11, which is msyqli_connect function and it works. Here's the rest of the index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'include/dbHandlers/dbConfig.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed! " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
        echo "connection sucess!";
}

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)  {
//      $query = 'SELECT * FROM quotes_tb ORDER BY id';
//      $sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);   

        $response->getBody()->write("Hello world");
        return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? I expect to see a `new` keyword in front of `mysqli_connect`. Otherwise the error message makes no sense.

Comment: Can you check your `phpinfo();` to confirm that the module `mysqli` is enabled.

Comment: this link says is fine https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp and yes it is enabled http://www.pctechtips.org/apps/slimpro/info.php